# Is there something wrong happening to my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Please,This is not right.

[How do i make skeletons formidable hand to hand fighters?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/115638/how-do-i-make-skeletons-formidable-hand-to-hand-fighters)

Comment: So just to clarify, you're asking why your question has accumulated downvotes and close votes?

Comment: @F1Krazy yes,I think my question is good enough and i feel this behaviour is not right and against the rules.

Comment: Please **[be nice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).**

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I try but not everyone is nice.

Comment: I think Molot and L.Dutch's comments explain it clearly enough. You state that your skeletons are "way weaker than humans for obvious reasons", but you haven't stated what those "obvious reasons" are, or in what ways they're weaker. We can't work around the limitations of your skeletons and turn them into effective fighters if we don't know what those limitations are.

Comment: @F1Krazy If an skeleton tried to stab you,He will be way slower by lack of muscles and blood,and everything...I stated my necros thralls are weak.

Comment: @Myrmidon Calling specific users out by name as "bad" is definitely not nice. Some of what was in the comments to that question of yours was absolutely borderline. You don't have to agree with everyone, and you certainly don't have to like everyone, but we do expect all users, newcomers and long-timers alike, to act civil and to assume good intentions of others.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well,This is not the first time to be honest >:(

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Im not perfect,But i saw worse questions with 0 downvotes and lots of answers,this is bullying againts me.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Also,Molot deleted 2 of his comments,Just saying -.-

Comment: @Myrmidon *"Molot deleted 2 of his comments"* You have literally no way of knowing that. Don't jump to conclusions about who did what.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Screenshot =)

Comment: Using comments to ask for clarification is not rude. Downvoting questions that don't provide the information needed to provide good answers is not rude. Name-calling, however, is **specifically** listed as an example of unacceptable behavior in the be nice policy which I already linked to above.

Comment: @Myrmidon *"If an skeleton tried to stab you,He will be way slower by lack of muscles and blood,and everything"* A skeleton cannot move. It's a collection of bones that can't even hold themselves together. If your skeletons can move, you're already introducing something that is not the same as in our world, so "obvious" is likely to not be so obvious. You might feel that it's "obvious", but for someone reading only what you've written in that question, I'd say that it's far from obvious why it's necessarily so. Giving the reason and not just claiming that it's obvious will help inform answers.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling So the magic tag is useless?

Comment: i did not delete any comment  there. My comments may be deleted by a bunch of people - diamond moderators, community management, developers, and so on.

Comment: Myrmidon, i don't think people are attacking you, i think they are wanting more information in the question, if you were to add what the obvious limitations are into the question then you won't attract any downvotes, a lot of the times, people downvote the question not the premise, if a good question is asked badly, or lacking details then it gets down voted, just add more info and the downvotes will stop

Comment: @Mołot Also ordinary users can delete comments by way of flags; in some cases by single flags (for example, comments containing certain trigger words are deletable by a single flag), in some cases requiring multiple flags.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I sure hope my comments did not contain any trigger words. Wasn't meant to.

Comment: @Mołot Just complementing your list with another way that comments can be deleted, is all.

Comment: For  "magic  tag  useless", please  see:   [Magic is primarily opinion-based by definition, so what does a POB VTC mean?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5991/809)

Answer (score 13):

Couple things I wanted to state explicitly:

1. I do my best not to look at the author name when I interact with post.
2. I interact mostly with posts on first pages of "new questions" and "active questions" lists, and review queues.
3. I'm active during certain parts of the day. If you happen to be usually active during similar period, you have higher chance to get a vote or comment from me. If someone posts mainly when I'm not active, it's quite possible I won't see (and thus vote, flag etc) his posts even if they deserve it. See point 2. If this gives someone wrong impression, I'm sorry, but I can't do anything about it.
4. I do downvote if question is poorly written. Yes, saying "obvious" when something is not, and refusing to elaborate, counts as "poorly written" and "not useful" to me, especially if supposedly obvious condition is crucial to the question.
5. I sometimes lack language skills, so if I seem snippy or ironic, it usually is language barrier, nothing more. I do my best to avoid that.
6. None of my real life friends are on Worldbuilding - or if they are, they never told me. Just saying.

Comment: Not that one opinion matters _at all_ but I find you one of the most helpful and even-handed users on the network, even if we do occasionally have some problems communicating effectively.

Comment: @Ash thank you. That's who I try to be. And I am aware of communication problems. The best I can do is the best I can do..

Comment: And generally you do very well, better than I do when I see certain phrases sometimes.

Comment: For what it's worth it's never crossed my mind that your native language wasn't English

Comment: @bendl Thank you. I read a lot and I watch Hollywood movies without translation (well, usually), so I may pretend ;)

Comment: Re: (6) I have one friend irl that's also on worldbuilding. I don't think we've interacted except by coincidence.

Answer (score 6):

I found the basic issue with your question to be simply this: without information, and a lot of it, about *where*, *how* and *to what degree* magic is involved in the process of getting a dead body moving again one cannot begin to understand the degree to which a resurrected "thrall" is impaired compared to a living human. If we don't have a starting point, beyond "weaker than a living person", we can't start to answer the rest of the question. For example the "standard" DnD skeleton is held together and animated by magic powered by the soul of the creature it used to be, it's strength is based in large part on the power of personality of that being rather than it's former physicality. On the other hand in the *Dresden Files* it is the age of the remains that dictate their power, the freshly dead are weak as kittens but even the smallest dinosaur skeleton is terrifyingly powerful. Without understanding the limits and details of your approach to these issues we don't stand a chance of effectively answering you question.

As to the apparent asymmetry you feel you see in question quality, you need to understand that questions with certain tags, [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) and [evolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution) are the ones that come immediately to mind have to be *better* than questions that simply ask for a [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) or about extrapolations from existing [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons), better is maybe the wrong word; they have to be more exact and more detailed in order to be answered well, or in some cases answered at all.