# Do we need the [names] tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Right now [names](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) has 36 questions. A lot of them are on hold or closed, and I feel none of them needs that tag to make sense.

I feel asking about names, or name conventions, usually tends to get questions closed as POB. Burninating this tag should help discourage this kind of question.

Should we do it?

Answer (score 4):

Closed questions are ones that shouldn't be here in the first place. Amount of such questions with a tag is a clue, but shouldn't be a deciding factor. This leaves us with:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=[names]+closed%3Ano

18 results. There are examples that really makes sense:

- Why would a city not use names?
- Searching for a database of real historical names
- What factors cause a society where people have no family name?
- Culturally Correct Naming Conventions
- How can I develop names for my fantasy land?

These are a really nice questions that are mostly about names.

**I'd say - let the tag be.** Questions about names can be OK, great even. Tag is useful for search and categorization. At the same time, we should have a meta post about names, like we have [one about magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5991/809), to help users understand which questions about names are OK, and which are not.